# What is this recycler view or listview it contains four buttons?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I want to create a expandable list with four child buttons in a row. And also click  working on that buttons. what can i use in android studio. i have checked so many even tried expandable `ListView` that is generating child in the vertical manner.

[image]

Comment: did you try creating a recyclerview with a custom layout?

Comment: yes but not able to create this view @payam

Comment: try this library https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Use ExpandableListView and in the group_child_layout take four ImageView(Whatever Buttons).

Assign respective data(e.g assign a phone number value to call_icon). Example below:

```
 @Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ChildHolder childHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_group_child, parent, false);
        childHolder = new ChildHolder();
        convertView.setTag(childHolder);
    }
    else {
        childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    /* Assign all the buttons their respective data from ContactData object*/

    return convertView;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Use ExpandableListView and in the group_child_layout take a RecyclerView(for horizontal buttons list) in it. Example below:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ChildHolder childHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_group_child, parent, false);
        childHolder = new ChildHolder();
        convertView.setTag(childHolder);
    }
    else {
        childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    childHolder.horizontalListView = (RecyclerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttons);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    childHolder.horizontalListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ButtonsAdapter horizontalListAdapter = new ButtonsAdapter(context, brands.get(groupPosition).buttons);
    childHolder.horizontalListView.setAdapter(horizontalListAdapter);

    return convertView;
}
```